# Programatically Create and Select Values From Components - Swing

Tags: java, swing

I've got this method which adds some instructions, a button and JLabel to a JPanel on click but I need some way of selecting these three elements so I can style them, I'm using a solution of iterating through all components and finding the ones I want to style but It won't let me set the border of the JPanels, it's not an option when you view available methods. Is there anyway to set the border of the JLabel in the loop at the bottom? OR a way to individually select each element.

When the user clicks a button on a different JPanel the GenerateImageArea method runs.

```
public void GenerateImageArea(int id)
{
    areaHeight += 200; // Extends JPanel

    i++;

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = i;
    gbc.gridwidth = 4;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    // Add the instructions JLabel
    add(new JLabel("["+ (id+5) + "]: Select an image of maximum dimensions 720 * 350 pixels."), gbc);

    i++;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = i;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    // Add a button to load an image
    add(new JButton("Load Image"));

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 3;
    // Add the JLabel which acts as a space to display the image
    add(new JLabel(""));

    // Set colour + font of the instructions JLabel
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getComponentCount(); i++) {
        Component comp = this.getComponent(i);
        if (comp.toString().contains("]:")) {
            comp.setForeground(Settings.SITE_GREEN);
            comp.setFont(Settings.SUBTITLEFONT);
        }
        else if (comp.toString().contains("")) {
            // I need to change the border of the second JLabel
        }
    }
}
```

Similar to this I need to programatically add JTextAreas then style and retrieve the data from them after the user clicks submit. How can i programatically add components but be able to extract the input afterwards?

Comment: Why don't you use variables? `JLabel label = ...; add(label); label.setBorder(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of finding the elements that you want to style, you can style them directly. For example, instead of doing this:

```
add(new JLabel("["+ (id+5) + "]: Select an image of maximum dimensions 720 * 350 pixels."), gbc);
```

you can do:

```
// Create instruction label
JLabel instruction = new JLabel("["+ (id+5) + "]: Select an image of maximum dimensions 720 * 350 pixels."); 
// Style it
instruction.setForeground(Settings.SITE_GREEN);
instruction.setFont(Settings.SUBTITLEFONT);
// Add it.
add(instruction, gbc);
```

I believe this approach is easier, and less error prone.

Comment: I've also got a similar method that adds instructions + text boxes for user input, say that I give all the text boxes a variable name like in your example - how can I extract the data from each one? - say for example if there are 10 text boxes on the screen?

Comment: You can store these labels and text boxes in an array. To extract the data, you just need to iterate over the array.

Comment: Oo you just got me thinking ... maybe something with a Hashtable, the key could be the name and the component the data ... hmmm,  one last thing before i tick it - is there anyway to programatically set the name of components to variables?

Comment: May be you can give examples? I don't quite understand the question.

Comment: Like Jlabel --myvariable-- = new JLabel();

Comment: I don't think it is possible. But, you can associate name with component using Hashtable.